# Magento ::: Using getBodyClass() in header.html

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

I am having trouble with working out how to access a method from outside its scope.

In my case ::::

```
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode().' '.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
```

That is code from 2columns-left.phtml

**I want to use the getBodyClass method in header.html**, like so ::::

```
<div class="header <?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' '.$this->getBodyClass().'':'' ?>">
```

But because getBodyClass() is a method of Mage_Page_Block_Html, it doesn’t work with $this in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header.

Can anyone help me with adjusting this code

```
<div class="header <?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' '.$this->getBodyClass().'':'' ?>">
```

for use in header.html? Or point me int he right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a CSS rule**

You could avoid this kerfuffle and us declarations in your stylesheet that make use of the class that's on the body element, e.g:

```
body.2column-left .header {
   ...
}
```

**Create the page/html block**

I'd suggest using the CSS rule above.  But if you *really* need access to the `page/html` block for that method, then you could create an instance of the block and access it directly with:

```
 $body_classes = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("page/html")->getBodyClass();
```

Comment: The `page/html` block has already been created, you only need to `getBlock('root')`

Answer (score 4):

The body class is set on a `page/html` block when that block is instantiated.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_urls = array(
        'base'      => Mage::getBaseUrl('web'),
        'baseSecure'=> Mage::getBaseUrl('web', true),
        'current'   => $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri()
    );

    $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
    if ($action) {
        $this->addBodyClass($action->getFullActionName('-'));
    }

    $this->_beforeCacheUrl();
}
```

The only way you can grab it from another block is to instantiate **another** `page/html.`

```
<?php
//from any block template context
$body_class = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html')->getBodyClass();
?>
...
<div class="header <?php echo $body_class?>">
```

Or to get a reference to an existing `page/html` block.

```
<?php
$body_class = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getBodyClass();
?>
```

Comment: Thank Alan, using `$this->getLayout()->createBlock("page/html")->getBodyClass();` didn't give me all the classes, whereas `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getBodyClass();` did. Very useful.